# Increment number stored as array of digit-counters

Tags: math

I'm trying to store a counter that can become very large (well over 32 and probably 64-bit limits), but rather than use a single integer, I'd like to store it as an array of counters for each digit. This should be pretty language-agnostic.

In this form, `0` would be `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` (one zero, none of the other digits up to 9). `1` would be `[0, 1, 0, ...]` and so on. `10` would therefore be `[1, 1, 0, ...]`.

I can't come with a way to keep track of which digits should be decremented (moving from `29` to `30`, for example) and how those should be moved. I suspect that it can't be done without another counter, either a single value representing the last cell touched, or an array of 10 more counters to flag when each digit should be touched.

Is it possible to represent a number in this fashion and count up without using a simple integer value?

Comment: that representation makes no sense whatsoever - how can you possibly tell which digit position any particular number is supposed to appear in?  For example, 121 and 211 would have the same representation.

Comment: Rather than storing frequency counts of the digits, have you considered just storing an array of the digits themselves? That gives a much more convenient representation to work with.

Comment: @templatetypedef or, you know, storing them in binary, since forcing a computer to do stuff in base 10 is _so_ much easier.... (not)

Comment: @Alnitak They would, which is why I suspect having some other storage is necessary. I'm curious if this is even vaguely possible, though. The constant-size storage for very large numbers would be nifty.

Comment: This is purely an experiment in trying to avoid using a bignum library.

Comment: It's impossible to store an unlimited size number in constant storage.  That's trivial information theory.  Use the bignum library, or if you know that just a few more bits would be sufficient, just use 2x 64-bit words.

Comment: @ssube Any particular reason not to use the bignum library? That sounds like exactly the tool for the job here.

Comment: Alnitak's concern with digit ordering is right. Why not store a `decimal` and keep the value between 1 and 10, then use an `int` for power of ten to multiply it by? That'll get you 10^2 billion

Comment: @templatetypedef Not sure how they perform in JS (where this will probably be implemented), and curious if it's possible to do otherwise. Mostly curiosity.

Comment: @AronFoster Need to represent numbers up to at least 10^23 digits, all integers.

Comment: @ssube If performance is your bottleneck, I'd be floored if you could outperform a custom bignum library. It would be surprising if your off-the-shelf implementation would outperform a well-tested, tuned, and debugged library.

Comment: A [decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) would work just fine for anything up to 10^28

Comment: @Aron *iff* he's using C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this representation by itself would be useless because it fails to encode digit position, leading to many numbers having the same representation (e.g. 121 and 211).

Either use a bignum library, or 80-bits worth of raw binary (that being sufficient to store your declared range of 10e23)